# Axios DELETE request failes only in the browser with 403 "Invalid CORS request" as response

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

1. I am using vue in the front end and spring boot in the back end .
2. I have used axios to make server call from the vue code .
3. Every thing was fine  with GET ,POST requests.
4. When i try to make DELETE request it failed with `403` status and the error response is `Invalid CROS request`.
5. But the same `DELETE` request works In POSTMAN

I have tried the following solution mentioned in the another post and it didn't help me 
1. added withCredentials: true in the request header

2. added headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest','X-CSRFToken': 'your token here'}

3.added @CrossOrigin annotation in the `DELETE` api

This is how i created  axios instance

```
const token = localStorage.token;

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/",
  headers: {
    Authorization: token
  }
});
```

making request as below

```
instance.delete(`/user/${username}`);
```

It throws `403` `Invalid CROS Request` as response and its not hitting the server api too

Comment: Did you enabled cros on server api side

Comment: i have added @CrossOrigin annotation in the delete api

Comment: I guess u mean cors and not cros. Could you show us how you added cross origin

Comment: For Cros , your side cros config  addition will not fulfills the requirement. Server side also needs to enable.  Please check at server api allows cros or not

Comment: ya sorry it is "Invalid CORS request" error i have configured cors in my delete api like below
    `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
    @DeleteMapping("/{username}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteUserByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username)
    {
        User user= userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }`
 
 origins -  client URL which request from the server

Comment: @MuniKumar you mean adding crossOrigin annotation  in the server side api alone is not enough .. i have read in another forum and found this easiest way to enable cors in the server side . Can u help me if i am missing some thing in the server side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You need to allow methods also 

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer 
{  
   @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) 
  {


      registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");
  }

}
```

or if you are configuring at controller and method level

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class HomeController 
{
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://example.com")
    @DeleteMapping("/{username}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteUserByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username) 
    { 
      User user= userRepository.findByUsername(username); 
      userRepository.delete(user); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after removing a piece of code from the spring security configuration file which adds default crosconfiguration

```
@Beanpublic CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());

        return source;
    }
```

applyPermitDefaultValues method of CorsConfiguration  adds only GET,POST,HEAD methods